# Does the Dailymotion API have something equivalent to YouTube's onYouTubeIframeAPIReady?

Tags: dailymotion-api

With the YouTube JS API, I can do the following:

```
<script src="//www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        ytPlayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer');
    }
</script>
```

This will load the API, and when its ready, assign `ytPlayer`.

However, the Dailymotion API is included as follows:

```
<script src="//api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>
<script>
    DM.init();
</script>
```

This doesn't wait for the API to be ready. So I'll often get `Uncaught ReferenceError: DM is not defined` errors. Does Dailymotion have a way to wait for the API to be ready before it executes code?

Comment: Have you tried placing `DM.init();` into a DOM ready function? Example `window.onload=function(){ DM.init(); };`

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to load the SDK in your site is to load it asynchronously: [example loading asynchronously](https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-javascript-loading-asynchronously)

You can then subscribe to the event 'apiready'

[event subscribe documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-javascript-methods-eventsubscribe)

[list of events](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-api-events)